# C# replace string containing \" to "

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

I have a string as below.

```
"alphabet": "dtSearch Alphabet File\n\n[Letters] // Original letter, lower case, upper case, unaccented\n""ReserveChar": "{\"Datasource\":[{\"text\":\"!\",\"value\":\"!\"},{\"text\":\"^\",\"value\":\"^\"},{\"text\":\"|\",\"value\":\"|\"},{\"text\":\"$\",\"value\":\"$\"}],\"macro\":\"@\",\"fuzzychar\":\"%\",\"stemming\":\"~\",\"phonic\":\"#\",\"shynonyms\":\"&\",\"wightchar\":\":\",\"matchdigitchar\":\"=\"}
```

I want to replace it as below.

```
"alphabet": "dtSearch Alphabet File\n\n[Letters] // Original letter, lower case, upper case, unaccented\n","ReserveChar": "{"Datasource":[{"text":"!","value":"!"},{"text":"^","value":"^"}],"macro":"@","fuzzychar":"%"}
```

Note that there are two sections in the string.

- Alphabet (Contains \n which is important on UI so I should not make changes in it)
- List item (It contains data source and currently contains \" which needs to be replaced to ")

**Note: I am migrating data so I can not resolve these issue from code side (JavaScript). I have to insert proper data in the database. so the code will work as it is.**

Basically, I want to replace \ (backslash) in the ReserveChar but not from the alphabet. So I want patter which replaces \" to ".

Below is what I have done so far.

```
(new Regex(@"\\")).Replace(newstring, "");
```

Above code works properly but replaces \ from alphabet also.

What changes should I do?

Please suggest solution apart from regex too if it can resolves an issue.

Comment: Would Replace("\\\"", "\"") do?

Comment: but that replaces "\n" to ""n" as well which is not good.

Comment: It does not do that. It replaces \" with "

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It seems the string contains json but your replacements will make it invalid json, can you explain the rationale behind your question?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I have already mentioned in the question that I am working on to migrate data only. So I have to follow the existing pattern. I have no access to the project that is used for UI. If I had code which processed the data from DB, I would have made changes in it.

Comment: If that answers my concern for you then that's OK with me but I am still left wondering why you are taking (almost) valid JSON and making it invalid, on purpose.

Comment: In any case, **there is absolutely no replace pattern** that will get you from the first string to the second string since the first string contains a lot more than what you want to replace. Specifically, it also contains `{"text":"|","value":"|"},{"text":"$","value":"$"}` and `"stemming":"~","phonic":"#","shynonyms":"&","wightchar":":","matchdigitchar":"="`

Comment: However, to get rid of the backslashes in front of the quotes, @PepitoSh has already given you the pattern to use. And no, it will not replace the `\n`.